# Cannot implicity convert type 'System.Collection.Generic.IEnumberable<double> to double"

Tags: c#, linq

Been posting alot recently. I've been trying to work out this problem.

I'm sending in a double[] and a double in a method in order to work out the files who are
bigger than the second value.

```
private static double medelvärdetBeräkning(double[] temp, double eftersökt)
{
    double störreÄn = temp.Where(o => o > eftersökt);
    return störreÄn;
}
```

But all I get is "Cannot implicity convert type 'System.Collection.Generic.IEnumberable to double""

Would really appreciate if someone could teach me the thinking and provide insight rather than a plain solution. Appreciate it

Edit:
This is obviously not all of the code. But I'm asking a user for an input (eftersökt) and then I want the method to work through the textfile and return all the values bigger than the userInput and return them in a list (this all works, it's just this method that is faulty)

Comment: What you want to return?

Comment: `Where` returns an `IEnumerable<T>` not a double. You need to return an `IEnumerable<double>` from your method

Comment: Maybe you want `First` or `Single` instead of `Where`.

Comment: the problem is exactly as the error says, the .`Where` LINQ extension gives back a `IEnumerable<T>` which your are thrying to put in a `double`

Comment: `Where` returns an `IEnumerable`.  If you want just one, use `First` or similar instead.  If you want to return an `IEnumerable`, change your method signature

Comment: seeing your edit, you want to return a list then just change the return type to `List<double>` and `return temp.Where(o => o > eftersökt).ToList();`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

based on your edit stating `return all the values`, you want:

```
private static List<double> medelvärdetBeräkning(double[] temp, double eftersökt)
{
        var störreÄn = temp.Where(o => o > eftersökt).ToList();
        return störreÄn;
}
```

That error message means what your returning is not what you said you'd be returning.  There's a type mismatch.  Check your return type vs. your method signature to identify the problem in the future.

Answer (score 1):

[`Enumerable.Where`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534803%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) will return another `IEnumerable<T>` - So I assume you wanted to either

1. Return all items greater than, or;
2. Return a specific item (The first, the last, the maximum etc)

If (1) is accurate change your method signature:

```
private static IEnumerable<double> medelvärdetBeräkning ....
```

If (2) is accurate change your method body, for example:

```
private static double medelvärdetBeräkning(double[] temp, double eftersökt)
{
    double störreÄn = temp.First(o => o > eftersökt);
    return störreÄn;
}
```

(In this example, you can use `Min`, `Max`, `Last` or `Average` etc in place of `First` depending on which specific item you want.)